# Merging two sheets into one

Tags: excel

I want to merge two files in excel, e.g.:

```
File 1 - 
col1 col2
1    3    
1    4   
2    5
2    6
3    7

File 2 -
Col2
101
102
103

Expected Output -
col1 col2 col3
1    3     101
1    4     101
2    5     102
2    6     102
3    7     103
```

Thanks

Comment: People are more willing to help, if you show some effort, or what you have tried so far. A great resource in general is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Welcome to SO, Nithya : )

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What are you looking for vba, formula?  Also please post any attempts you have tried in your original post.  SO is not a code for me site.  And you will get more help with a more specific question.

Comment: Also see a similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/662008/how-to-merge-data-from-multiple-excel-files-into-a-single-excel-file-or-access-d

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Col2` in File 2 is in B2, 'label' a column:

```
=OFFSET(B$1,INT(ROW()/2),)
```

copy down to suit and then copy the values from that column into File1 where required.

[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)
[INT](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/INT-function-A6C4AF9E-356D-4369-AB6A-CB1FD9D343EF)
[ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D)